# Rails delete_all is not deleting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a rails 3.2.8 app with the following models: Profile and Report. Profile has many Reports, and of Reports belong to a Profile

If I try to delete_all of the reports for a specific profile:

```
Profile.first.reports.delete_all
```

Instead of deleting the reports, it just sets their profile_id to nil using SQL similar to:

```
UPDATE `reports` SET `profile_id` = NULL WHERE `reports`.`profile_id` = 1 AND `reports`.`id` IN (1, 3)
```

I can't find anything about this in the guides, is this the correct behaviour? And if not what would cause it?

It's worth noting that using destroy_all works normally, as does using destroy and delete on a singular Report.

**Edit** (as I can't answer my own question yet):

Changing the relationship of the profile from:

```
has_many :reports
```

to:

```
has_many :reports, dependent: :delete_all
```

has fixed this, I'm guessing if you don't specify depending, it defaults to :nullify, and calling Profile.first.reports.delete_all doesn't actually delete, it instead does what ever is specified in dependant.

Unless I'm missing something this behaviour is undocumented, but at least it works as I expect now.

Comment: Why not try Report.where('profile_id = ?', profile.id).destroy_all ?

Answer (score 3):

If you have defined the association between profile and reports then your code should work else you can try

```
Report.where(:profile_id => Profile.first.id).delete_all
```

Comment: This does work, as does

`Report.delete_all(profile_id: Profile.first.id)`

But I'l really like to know why the normal delete_all isn't working

Comment: because in the back ground rails is running something line
SELECT `profiles`.* FROM `profiles` LIMIT 1
 SELECT `reports`.* FROM `reports` WHERE `reports`.`profile_id` = 1

Answer (score 0):

I've test it just a bit, but it should work for your case:

```
Report.delete_all(profile_id: Profile.first.id)
```